# How to add command (contextmenu item) to office communicator 2007 R2?

Tags: contextmenu, office-communicator

I am working on Office Communicator feature where I want to add a context menu item to the office communicator. I followed the steps given at;
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819982(v=office.13).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819982%28v=office.13%29.aspx)

But I am not able to see any menu item. I modified the registry with the given script.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Communicator\SessionManager\Apps{1F9F07C6-7E0B-462B-AAD7-98C6DBEA8F69}]
>   "Name"="Contoso Sales Contact Manager" "HelpMessage"="The Contoso
>   Sales Contact Manager is not installed. Contact the Help Desk for more
>   information." "ApplicationType"="REG_DWORD:00000000"
>   "ApplicationInstallPath"="C:\cltest.exe" "Path"="C:\cltest.exe
>   %user-id% %contact-id%" "SessionType"="REG_DWORD:00000001"
>   "ExtensibleMenu"="ConversationWindowActions;MainWindowRightClick"

Am I missing anything else ? Please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, I am coding in C#. It was by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution on Microsoft forum. Thought to share it on StackOverflow for other users, if anyone is looking for it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicatorsdk/thread/6662b7ef-db14-4340-a8b2-f8fb1fc6f4ab